# How to sort a list of numbers and group results chronologically by range

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Take the following list:

```
445
446
661
662
1978
1979
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2021
2022
2673
2674
```

What is the best approach to sort this list so you end up with a result that groups all the number ranges found in the list chronologically?

E.g, wanted result would be 5 arrays:

```
[445, 446]
[661, 662]
[1978, 1979]
[2014 ... 2022]
[2673, 2674]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = array(
    445,446,661,662,1978,1979,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,
    2021,2022,2673,2674
);

$result = array();
$tmp = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($i + 1, $array) && ($array[$i + 1]) - $array[$i] == 1) {
        $tmp[] = $array[$i];
    } else {
        $tmp[] = $array[$i];
        $result[] = $tmp;
        $tmp = array();
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 445
      1 => int 446
  1 => 
    array
      0 => int 661
      1 => int 662
  2 => 
    array
      0 => int 1978
      1 => int 1979
  3 => 
    array
      0 => int 2014
      1 => int 2015
      2 => int 2016
      3 => int 2017
      4 => int 2018
      5 => int 2019
      6 => int 2020
      7 => int 2021
  4 => 
    array
      0 => int 2021
      1 => int 2022
  5 => 
    array
      0 => int 2673
      1 => int 2674
```

**NOTE:**

There are two 2021 value in your array. Maybe you can use `array_unique` to get only the unique values.

Comment: Just add `sort($array);` your function only work with ordered array

Comment: Beautiful, works perfect ;) And yeah the final array would have all unique entries

Comment: You are welcome. I hope, you can use `array_unique` and `sort` functions.